# logstash not reading multiple files

Tags: file, date, input, logstash

My Kibana5.6.8 logstash configuration seems only reading one log file
My logstash.conf on  /home/elastichsearch/confLogs is

```
input { 
file {
type => "static"
path => "/home/elasticsearch/static_logs/**/*Web.log*" exclude => "*.zip"
start_position => beginning
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"        
}
}

filter {
if [type] == "static" {
if [message] !~ /(.+)/  {
drop { }
}
grok{
patterns_dir => "./patterns"
overwrite => [ "message" ]
# 2017-08-07 11:47:35,466 INFO  [http-bio-10.60.2.19-10267-exec-60] jsch.DeployManagerFileUSImpl (DeployManagerFileUSImpl.java:155) - Deconnexion de l'hote qvizzza3
# 2017-08-07 11:47:51,775 ERROR [http-bio-10.60.2.19-10267-exec-54] service.BindingsRSImpl (BindingsRSImpl.java:143) - Can't find bindings file deployed on server
# 2017-08-03 16:01:11,352 WARN  [Thread-552] pcf2.AbstractObjetMQDAO (AbstractObjetMQDAO.java:137) - Descripteur de
match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate},%{INT} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}  \[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\] %{JAVACLASS:package} \(%{JAVAFILE:className}:%{INT:line}\) - %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
}
# 2017-08-03 16:01:11,352
date{
match => [ "logdate", "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" ]
target => "logdate"
}
}
}

output {
elasticsearch { hosts => ["192.168.99.100:9200"]}
```

My logs directory, with load balanced logrotate files

```
static_logs
--prd1
----mlog Web.log
----mlog Web.log.1
----mlog Web.log.2
--prd2
----mlog Web.log
----mlog Web.log.2
```

Where is my mistake ?
My patterns are on /home/elasticsearch/confLogs/patterns/grok-patterns qui with TIMESTAMP_ISO8601

Regards

Comment: Wen i manualliy concate my log files ton one log file and running   path => "/home/elasticsearch/static_logs/*Web.log" exclude => "*.zip", that's Ok kibana see logdate as date field !!!

Comment: It seems me logs files are not correctly order by writting date ?

Answer (score 0):

If my log files are more 140M, logdate filter is not viewing as an date field, but as an string field !!!